# How can I find an element from object data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to locate an element using two attributes, where one is a data object.

Take this code...

Html:

```
<div data-div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var m = { "Name": "John", "Age": 38 };
    $("[data-div]").data("user", m);
    $("[data-div]").html($("[data-div]").data("user").Name); 
    $("[data-div][data-user-Name='John']").html("YES!"); // <-- doesn't work
});
```

In the last line above, I try to get the element by a data key and a data object (user = John).

How can I do that, since the above doesn't work?

Here's a fiddle sample...
http://jsfiddle.net/VcjE3/

Comment: That's not how it works.  Why don't use the same API ($.data) you used to set the data with, to get the data with, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `$("[data-div]").data("user", m);` [will not create a `data-*` attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/CdqLk/). This is not [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is for. `.data()` does not mean "adding `data-*` attributes", instead, they are for adding arbitrary data to the specific nodes.

You will have to use `attr()` to add `data-*` attributes:

```
$("[data-div]").attr({
    "data-user-name": "John",
    "data-user-age": 38
});
```

---

To search for jQuery data values, try this:

```
$("[data-div]").filter(function(){
    return $(this).data("user").Name == "John";
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here. Well this line work perfectly .... $("[data-div]").data("user").Name ... so it's stored fine, I just can't search for it.

Comment: @MojoDK - Yes it stored it, but it's not stored as a `data-*` attribute. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a data value with `.data('')` it isn't stored as an attribute.
You'll either have to set the attribute with `.attr('data-user-name','John')` or you have to find the element using the `filter()` function:

```
$('[data-div]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('user').Name == 'John';
});
```